# Console app Desktop size

Tags: c#, console, desktop

How can i get the desktop size from a console application?

Regular commands from WPF or Windows Forms won't work and i wasn't able to come up with a solution!

```
SystemParameters.VirtualScreenWidth   
SystemParameters.VirtualScreenHeight

SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width   
SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height
```

None of them work

Comment: What do you mean by 'none of them work'. Are you getting incorrect values?

Comment: No, i can't even compile it because it doesn't recognize those commands as they don't belong to Console Applications!

Comment: You need to add the dll references. For SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width add a reference to System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Please don't add answer to question - if you get an answer - accept it, if you found answer yourself - post *separate answer* (known as ["self-answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add System.Windows to references for SystemParameters and System.Windows.Forms for SystemInformation.

Comment: It doesn't recognize!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms assembly to make use of the SystemInformation.VirtualScreen property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.virtualscreen(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

u can get the size using the `screen` class check one of post.

http://mytactics.blogspot.ae/2013/12/change-screen-resolution-using-c.html

```
Screen Srn=Screen.PrimaryScreen;

int tempWidth=Srn.Bounds.Width;
int tempHeight=Srn.Bounds.Height;
Console.WriteLine("Current Screen width is {0} and height is {1}.", tempWidth, tempHeight);
```